# Namespace disappears when building RELEASE, but present on DEBUG

Tags: c#, wpf

The System.Windows.Interactivity namespace *vanishes* when I swap from DEBUG build to RELEASE build. My project fails to build (naturally), and gives the error and warning visible in the images below. The namespace simply disappears from the Object Browser as soon as I switch build modes, even though the reference is still present in the Solution Explorer.

What's going on here?! And how do I fix it?

[image: Debug Mode]

[image: Release Mode]

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried the usual general troubleshooting tips, such as **(a)** performing a "Clean" build, and/or **(b)** manually deleting all `bin` and `obj` subdirectories beneath your solution directory, and/or **(c)** restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: And: Where is the `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` located? Are you by any chance referencing the DLL that is inside the `bin\Debug` subdirectory? If so, you shouldn't do that. Put the DLL somewhere else in your solution directory, e.g. inside a `Lib\` folder.

Comment: Look at CSPROJ in a text editor. Likely one manually patched the file and broke RELEASE build (maybe included dependency with condition or in wrong section). Re-adding in VS may be fastest option.

Comment: I tried a clean>rebuild to no avail.
I went into the Debug folder and deleted the DLL present there, this now caused DEBUG to break identically to RELEASE. The reference is still present, however, and references the version in the solution folder, so I'm not sure why this is. The program is supposed to generate this DLL at start-up if it's not present, which I had working. Maybe it needs to have a copy present in the output folder to build, but not to run when already built?

Comment: Perhaps add a description or screenshot of the assembly reference properties for `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your question. Please describe also where exactly that DLL is located and how you added an assembly reference for it to your project.

Comment: Alexei: It may be that you were right. Deleting and re-adding the reference seems to have solved the problem. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: stakx: It's too late to take a screen shot, now, but I saw that the assembly was in Recent Assemblies, checked and showing it's location in the base solution directory. That's how I could tell.

Answer (score 3):

The reason can be you have linked to the dll that is placed inside Debug folder. If link shows relative path like ../my.dll when this dll will be not accessible from Release folder. You can replace relative link by full. But better solution will be moving dll above Debug and Release folder in folders hierarchy:

1. place dll somewhere above Debug and Release folders
2. remove old dll from References
3. add new dll to References

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to your build configurations; you can open the .csproj file with some good editor (Vim, Sublime, Notepad++) and take a search the reference you're missing. It is possible to reference different libraries depending on the build configuration, so maybe the reference of this library is not included in the "Build | Release" mode, or it is defined specifically in the "Build | Debug" configuration section instead of the common one.